# How to cancel pyspark foreachPartition operation

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can I cancel a long pyspark foreachPartition operation?

For example I have my code that handles a very large amount of data (and it take a long time) but I want to be able to allow the user to cancel the operation - how do I do it?

```
def get_data(self, spark_session):
    query = 'Some query...'
    my_data_frame = spark_session.sql(query)
    my_data_frame.foreachPartition(handle_data)
    # How to cancel on user request?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using

```
sc = spark_session.sparkContext
sc.setJobGroup(...)
# In a separate thread:
sc.cancelJobGroup(...)
```

There is a full example in [PySpark API documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.setJobGroup)

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for (:

Comment: And an important note for anyone that uses this code - it works but spark has a small bug: if you call the cancelJobGroup too soon (right as the job starts) spark ignores the cancel and continues the job. I've added a few seconds delay before calling cancelJobGroup and it solved the issue.